# How to display a single row in jtable based on user input?

Tags: jquery, jquery-jtable

I have two dependent dropdowns, when the user selects value of the second dropdown and hits submit button, I want to extract the value of the selected option( which acts as the primary key) and display an entire row in jtable whose primary key is the selected value.

Can someone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

First of all your question is unclear. You want to display the entire row in the table based on option selected. 
But you have not mentioned where is the database? Whether there is a oracle database or you have stored it in an array.

Anyhow, I am assuming that you have an 2-D array called "arr". 
Even if you have oracle tables, please use PHP and extract those table values and save it in a 2D array.

Let us take an example where the table has 2 attributes - name and price and we will select "name" from dropdown and print name and price in table.

Here is the basic HTML code for dropdown and table defination -

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="functions.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<select id="drop">
    <option value="Abc">ABC</option>
    <option value="Def">DEF</option>
    <option value="Ghi">GHI</option>
    <option value="Jkl">JKL</option>
</select> 

<table id="tblData">            
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

In the function.js file, code is -

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#drop').on('change', function() { 
   //check on selection of dropdown menu

   var name=$( "#drop" ).val();
   //saving value of dropdown in variable name
   var i;
   for(i=0;i<arr[0].length;i++)
    if(arr[i][0]==$name
        var price=arr[i][1];
   //saving price for corresponding name 

   $("#tblData tbody").append(
    "<tr><td>"+$name+"</td><td>"+$price+"</td></tr>
    "</tr>");
   //appending in table
   });
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks so much for the reply. And also this was my first question on stackoverflow, so I am really sorry for posting the question in an incomplete manner.

I am using MySql 5.5 database and java servlets. I am using the jquery plugin jtable to display data from the database. This is the API reference for the plugin: [http://www.jtable.org/ApiReference].

The plugin uses a list action to display all the values from a particular table. I am trying to use the plugin to just display one row from the table based on the value of the option selected in the dropdown.